# Getting Records from SQL Table by checking Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the table structure as follows

```
ID    DefID    AttrID    ValInt     ValReal    ValDate    ValStr
1      1         1        NULL       NULL        NULL      hi
2      1         1        NULL       NULL        NULL      hi
3      1         1        NULL       NULL        NULL      hi
4      1         1        NULL       NULL        NULL      hi
1      1         1           0       NULL        NULL      NULL
2      1         1           1       NULL        NULL      NULL
3      1         1           0       NULL        NULL      NULL
4      1         1           0       NULL        NULL      NULL
```

This is my table named Table, Now I want to get the ID by query only having ValStr='h1' and ValInt=1, meaning only those ID whose ValStr is hi and also ValInt = 1 belonging to the same ID column. Please help.

Here what I have did till Now.

```
select ID from Table where DefID=1 and ValStr='hi' and  ValInt=1
```

My Actual answer should be

```
ID
 2
```

but I am getting this from the above query

```
ID
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: can you explain why `2` is your desired result?

Comment: your desired result is NULL isn't it?

Comment: No, the ID column isn't an actual ID. He's looking for IDs that have one row with the specified ValStr and another row with the specified ValInt. (I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more option

```
select t1.ID from Table t1
where EXISTS (
              SELECT *
              FROM Table t2
              WHERE t2.DefID = 1 AND t2.ValStr = 'hi'
              ) and  t1.ValInt = 1
```

Comment: This is more correct, I just want to get result whose DefID is 1. Thats rights. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    TableName
WHERE   (DefID = 1 AND ValInt = 1) OR
        (DefID = 1 AND ValStr = 'hi')
GROUP   BY ID
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e582/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT distinct t1.ID 
FROM Table t1 
JOIN Table t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.DefID=1 and t2.DefID = 1
AND t1.ValStr='hi' and  t2.ValInt=1
```

or (depending on taste)

```
SELECT distinct t1.ID 
FROM Table t1 
JOIN Table t2 on t1.id = t2.id AND  t1.DefID=1 = t2.DefID
WHERE t1.DefID=1 AND t1.ValStr='hi' and  t2.ValInt=1
```

Comment: I think you have to remove the `t1.DefID=1 and t2.DefID = 1 AND` since seems he added it wrongly in his Query.

Comment: @flup, you Query worked, by replacing the real table name and column name. Not to expose my table name and column names, I have given wrong data. Thanks

Comment: SELECT  distinct t1.ID 
FROM LLAttrData t1 
JOIN LLAttrData t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.DefID=t2.DefID
AND t1.ValStr='hi' and  t2.ValInt=1

Comment: @TheIndianProgrammmer Or add it in the join, agreed.